# Facebook - LoginFragment on a SingleInstance activity

Tags: android, facebook

I am using Facebook SDK (4.3.0) LoginButton on a Fragment, that is hosted in an Activity with launchMode set to singleInstance, facebook login button seem to have problem with that, as when its pressed the login action gets canceled right away with this messege :

> Cannot call LoginFragment with a null calling package. This can occur
>   if the launchMode of the caller is singleInstance.

an odd thing to note is that this doesnt heppen on all devices, on most samsung devices it does but my sony xperia doesnt suffer from that, anyway, When i remove single instance launch mode it works fine, but then my activity can have multiple instances which brings weird user experience for the app users.

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As the error noted, launch mode of the caller class in a single instance or singleton class.

My fix was to call the singleton class on the onResume() method instead of onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)..

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    UserPresenter.getInstance().start(this);
}
```

The same line of code threw error with onCreate while worked fine with onResume.

Hope anyone with the issue shall have a fix.